# Oracle to_dsinterval not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to convert string to time. I am trying with `to_disinterval`. But it is not taking milliseconds.

How to convert string '09:12:09:352'? I am trying to use function like

```
to_disinterval('0 '||' '||SUBSTR('09:12:09:352',1,8)).
```

but it is not taking milliseconds and it is displaying 0 9:12:09.0

Please help me.

Regards,

Chaitu

Answer (score 4):

By using `SUBSTR(..., 1, 8)` you are precisely telling Oracle to ignore the milliseconds part, by taking only the first 8 characters of the `'09:12:09:352'` string. Get rid of SUBSTR and just use

```
to_dsinterval('0 '||' '||'09:12:09.352')
```

if that's what you need. Note that you also need to change the last colon to a period (the usual decimal separator).

Comment: Sorry, my bad: I forgot to change the last `:` to a `.`
Fixed now, and it works on Oracle 10g.

Comment: but i will get input with :,is there anyway to solve the problem

Comment: you could use e.g. `REGEXP_REPLACE` to fix it: if `time` is your input string having `:` instead of `.`, then using 
`regexp_replace(time, ':([0-9]{0,3})$', '.\1')` in place of it should fix it.

Comment: for instance:
`to_dsinterval(regexp_replace('0  09:12:09:352', ':([0-9]{0,3})$', '.\1'))` works.

Comment: Thanks fudo,i am trying to compare ,but it is giving error,like below: trunc('22-JUN-12')+to_dsinterval(regexp_replace('0 09:12:09:352', ':([0-9]{0,3})$', '.\1')) < trunc('22-JUN-12')+to_dsinterval(regexp_replace('0 09:30:00', ':([0-9]{0,3})$', '.\1'))

Comment: I suggested that regex under the assumption that the milliseconds part would always be present. If it is not, as in that 09:30:00 example, you'll need a more precise regex – counting the number of `:` and replacing only the third one, if present.

Comment: something like `regexp_replace(string, '(:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}):([0-9]{0,3})$', '\1.\2')`

Comment: select to_dsinterval(regexp_replace('09:30:00', '(:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}):([0-9]{0,3})$', '\1.\2')) from dual; not working and one more thing i observed in previous solution was adding 6 0's in the end.

Comment: I tried this also but not working:select to_dsinterval('0 '||' '||regexp_replace(string, '(:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}):([0-9]{0,3})$', '\1.\2')) from dual

Comment: Hi fudo, problem is I am getting sometimes input string as '09:30:00' and some times getting '09:30:20:154'

Comment: Fixed this issue using to_timestamp